# jquery with post OData service returns 501 not implemented

Tags: jquery, odata

I'm trying to send data to Web API using OData and able to debug Web API controller method but while returning model Web API is throwing an error '501 error code'

I have this call using JQuery:

```
  OData.request(
          {
              requestUri: "/odata/Products",
              method: "POST",
              data: {
                  ID:"22",
                  Name : "Hat1", 
                  Price: 122, 
                  Category : "Apparel" 
              }
          },
          function (data) {
              alert(data.Price);
          });
```

My controller is:

```
public class ProductsController : EntitySetController<Product, int>
    {
        ProductsContext _context = new ProductsContext();

        [Queryable]
        public override IQueryable<Product> Get()
        {
            return _context.Products;
        }

        protected override int GetKey(Product entity)
        {
            return entity.ID;
        }

        protected override Product GetEntityByKey(int key)
        {
            return _context.Products.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ID == key);
        }

        protected override Product CreateEntity(Product entity)
        {           

            return entity;
        }
}
```

`CreateEntity` method is working properly but in console log it is throwing '501 not implemented' error

Thanks..

Comment: Could you share the exception message?

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 501 (Not Implemented) http://localhost:64011/odata/User
HTTP request failed

Comment: what is OData.request in your example

Answer (score 1):

I tried post with HttpResponseMessage and it worked :)

```
public override HttpResponseMessage Post(UserEntity user)
            {


                var response = Request.CreateResponse(
                    HttpStatusCode.Created,
               `enter code here`     user);
                response.Headers.Location = new Uri(Url.ODataLink(
                    new EntitySetPathSegment("User"),
                    new KeyValuePathSegment(user.UserID.ToString())));
                return response;
            }
```